# Split the screen in two parts

Tags: android, colors, split, screen, draw

Ok I tried some methods but I failed...

My background painting code is like this:

```
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);
```

So as you can see that code will paint the whole screen with the color specified in background(xml);

The problem is that I want to Paint only about 65% of the upper screen part and the rest of 35% will remain black at the bottom part.I wanna do this because on the upper part I wanna write a question,and at the bottom I will have about 4 buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Setup top half
canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight()*0.65, background);
//Setup bottom half
canvas.drawRect(0,getHeight()*0.65, getWidth(), getHeight(), secondbackground);
```